# Присвоение С++

Tags: c++builder, windows, c++

Компилятор Buider C++. Нужно значение, которое получаю из Edit1 (Тип: AnsiString) присвоить переменной типа char. В интернете нашел функцию, которой теоретически это реализуемо - `c_str()`, но не работает.

Возможно будет совет, как обойтись без этого, потому пишу задание:

> Найти слово, в котором максимальное количество разных символов.

Например: "человек" и "кукушка" - выбрано должно быть "человек".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку речь идет об AnsiString, то далее предполагается, что символы суть байты. Из `Edit1` вы получаете строку, а пишете, что нужно присвоить значение переменной типа char &mdash; будем считать это опечаткой.

Наверное вы имели в виду получить доступ к массиву байтов. Функция `c_str()` вам не особо-то и нужна, поскольку для класса `AnsiString` перегружена операция `[]`, то есть вы можете обращаться к элементам строки по индексу. В отличие от традиционного массива байтов, первому символу вашей строки соответствует индекс `1`. Так как имеется метод `Length()`, который возвращает длину строки, вы легко можете обойти все символы строки.

Поиск количества различных символов в строке можно организовать по-разному, например, организовать и обнулить массив счетчиков `int counts[256] = {0};`, и для каждого считанного символа строки `myString` выполнять `counts[myString[i]] = 1`. Сумма (количество единичек) в массиве `counts` и будет равно количеству различных символов.

При написании этого ответа использовался [этот источник](http://cubook.supernew.org/manual-c/types/197-ansistring.html).

Comment: Все отлично, спасибо, но строку, грубо говоря, можно рассматривать и как значение и как некий массив символов. Хотя, честно говоря, я не понял 3-й абзац...

Comment: @Zein, чтобы определить слово с максимальным количеством различных символов, нужно иметь возможность это количество посчитать. В третьем абзаце описан один из возможных подходов. Каждому символу в AnsiString соответствует код - число в интервале от 0 до 255. Пусть исходная строка представляет собой последовательность символов "abac". Перебирая все символы в цикле, ставим единички в `counts['a']`, `counts['b']`, `counts['a']`, `counts['c']`. Теперь суммируем единички - их будет три штуки - три различных символа в этой строке.

Comment: вот теперь я понял,спасибо)